# Bar value depend on other bar value in HighChart

Tags: highcharts

I am developing bar chart using Highchart library.I created two y axis, first is for TAM and second for Share.Share is in percentage while TAM is not.For the Share y-axis value, I made the maximum value is 100 and it fixed, but for TAM the value is dynamic.

Referring to the graph

[http://jsfiddle.net/unidha/vGVRb/45/][1]

There a requirement to make Share bar height to depend on the Tam bar height. For example, currently Tam one is 12,300,000 unit and share one is 70% .Based on the graph, Share One is taller than Tam One because it has it's own axis.Now how I want to make the Share One's height is 70% from Tam One 's bar height?

Is it possible to do that?As my understanding for all this time, the bar height should be determined by the y-axis NOT based on other bar height.In case got solution for such requirement, what possibility it should be?

Here the same code that reside in above jsfiddle for your reference.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type:'column',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            alignTicks:false
        },
          title: {
            text: 'Performance Snapshot'
        },

        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Tam One   Share One ', ' Tam Two  Share Two  '],
            //NUR
            tickWidth:0
        }],

   yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
          labels: {
            //  format: '{value}%',
                style: {
                  //  color: '#89A54E'
                     color: 'FFFFFF'
                },
                //NUR
                step:2,
                y:0
            } ,
            min: 0,
             minRange:0.1,
             max:100,
            title: {
                text: 'Share',
                style: {
                 //   color: '#89A54E'
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
          title: {
                text: 'Tam',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },

            labels: {
              //NUR  format: '{value} unit',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Tam Unit',
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [12300000, 34400000],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' unit'
            },
             groupPadding: 0

        }, {
            name: 'Share',
            color: '#89A54E',
            type: 'column',
            data: [70,40],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            },
             groupPadding: 0
        }]

    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but you need to pass series data as calculated values, not percent, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/vGVRb/48/

```
tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        formatter: function () {
            var s = this.x,
                points = this.points,
                len = points.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var p = points[i];
                console.log(p);

                s += '<br><span style="color:' + p.series.color + '">' + p.series.name + '</span><span>: ' + p.point.label + '</span>';

            }

            return s;
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Tam Unit',
        color: '#4572A7',
        type: 'column',
        data: [{
            y: 12300000,
            label: '12300000 units'
        }, {
            y: 34400000,
            label: '34400000 units'
        }],
        groupPadding: 0

    }, {
        name: 'Share',
        color: '#89A54E',
        type: 'column',
        data: [{
            y: 12300000 * 0.7,
            label: '70%'
        }, {
            y: 34400000 * 0.4,
            label: '40%'
        }],
        groupPadding: 0
    }]
```

You can observe 'label' property under data, which is used later in tooltip.formatter to make sure you will display proper tooltip. Also, values are calculated accordingly to percentage in label.